# How to Copy to Selected for F-curve modifiers

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

I added the **F-curve modifiers** to all of the channels (location, rotation, scale). I want to fix the value and **Copy To Selected** to all other channels. But it seems impossible. I can't even delete all of F-curve modifiers at once.

Is there any way to work around it? Or I am doing wrong something

[image]

[image]